# Is it possible to control a stepper-motor with javascript?

Tags: gpio, python, hardware, remote

So I have seen some examples, how you can control servo-motors with javascript, but we use 2 stepper-motors for our project and these use an extra library in python. So is there a way to control them with javascript or to control a python script with javascript?

More information:

I want a mobile website or hybrid app to control these 2 stepper motors, just simple sliders to give them some speed and stop them. So the Web-Interface should communicate with WebSocket to my raspi. The WebSocket should be Socket.io with NodeJS. We use the Adafruit stepper-motor control-board, which has it's own library to control them.

Comment: JavaScript is a general purpose language so will be able to talk to a library to control gpios.  I suspect you want to run the JavaScript in a web browser which brings unique problems.  Could you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: I added some more information for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your first paragraph, yes, it's possible to call python from NodeJS, check out [ChildProcess](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html).  Using that facility you can then communicate directly with the Python program that actually controls the motors.

Answer (score 1):

Try nodejs on your RPi, and then use subprocess module of python to controlled javascript routines , I would also like you to check johnny-five lib of nodejs.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [jython](http://www.jython.org)
It is a python in javascript.

Comment: @Thunder: The original poster is incorrect. Jython is a python implementation written in Java.  Java and javascript are not related.

Comment: Oh, ok thanks I had no time yet to check that out, but thanks that saves me some time :)

Comment: Jython is short for Java-Python, not Javascript related at all