# wireless Controlling of a servo motor using Raspberry

Tags: raspbian, python, wireless, web

i have just started using raspberry pi and i have been able to wireless connect and access the Lxterminal of the Pi on my laptop by using a mini WiFi dongle with the Pi.I have good knowledge in Python too . Now i need to control two mini servo motors connected to Pi GPIO pins by using some kind of app or browser from a mobile device.I have no idea on how to do it. Please help me in this matter .
Raspberry is running on raspbian.

Comment: Welcome to the Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange community! In general please try to use the search box (in the top right corner of the page) as it often yields questions and answers that are related and have already got good solution. 8-)

Comment: Very relevant: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/33166/is-it-possible-to-control-a-stepper-motor-with-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can put together a fairly quick and dirty setup for this using [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org) (a Python based web 'microframework').

There are tutorials [here](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html) on using pigpio to control servos using Python. Get this working first!

The Flask homepage has both [quickstart](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#quickstart) and [slightly more in-depth](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/tutorial/#tutorial) tutorials on getting started with Flask.

I'm currently working on a small web system for some WS2812 LEDs, and found Flask and HTML (no javascript required!) sufficient to achieve basic tasks. I used the Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition template for a Python/Flask Web Project as a starting point to lay out the basic application structure, then deleted and tweaked as required to get things up and running.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://razzpisampler.oreilly.com/ch05.html) is would be a good start. I have tried python for the same but for a differnet apllication of servo Motor. try using the `python 3` in your raspberry pi.